# Can I use iOS local notifications if app is not running (like Clock app)?

Tags: notifications, swift4, ios11, unusernotificationcenter, unnotificationrequest

I'd like to use iOS local `UNNotifications` even if my app is not running. The same way we use Alarm in Clock app. We can setup Alarm, then quit our Clock app but... sound and notification will run on time. I need the same type of behaviour.

Is it possible?

My code's excerpt:

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

class ViewController: UIViewController, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Our title"
        content.body = "A body of message"
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 60, repeats: false)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "testID", content: content, trigger: trigger)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)  
    }
}
```

Comment: Alarm app use private API , all what you can do is to trigger notification at specific date to play only 30 sec sound , but built in IOS Alarm App have  special treatment from Apple

Comment: Could you answer my question and give me all Apple links if they exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SupportingNotificationsinYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH4-SW1)  About  30 seconds

> Local and remote notifications can specify custom alert sounds to be
>   played when the notification is delivered. You can package the audio
>   data in an aiff, wav, or caf file. Because they are played by the
>   system-sound facility, custom sounds must be in one of the following
>   audio data formats:
>
> Linear PCM
>
> MA4 (IMA/ADPCM)
>
> µLaw
>
> aLaw
>
> Place custom sound files in your app bundle or in the Library/Sounds
>   folder of your app’s container directory. Custom sounds must be under
>   **30 seconds when played**. If a custom sound is over that limit, the
>   default system sound is played instead.

Built-in Clock app made by Apple. have Special treatment (No way)

Comment: So, I can't treat my app with battery's level (the same way as Clock)? There are no words about Special Treatment. Only about sounds...

Comment: no as he said: you can schedule for specific date, 30s, with sound and text -- thats it